# Is Pegasus Meteor Fist a projectile?

Tags: saint-seiya

In the original *Saint Seiya* anime, it doesn't seem like [Pegasus Meteor Fist](https://saintseiya.fandom.com/wiki/Pegasus_Meteor_Fist) is a projectile. It looks like it is, but Seiya is often seen moving toward the enemy, which seems un-projectile-like to me and instead just like he punches really fast.

In more recent animes, we see some attacks are like projectiles attacking airplanes.

Is Pegasus Meteor Fist a projectile?

Answer (score 1):

From [Pegasus Meteor Fist | Seiyapedia | Fandom](https://saintseiya.fandom.com/wiki/Pegasus_Meteor_Fist):

> **Pegasus Meteor Fist** (ペガサス流星拳 *Pegasasu Ryūsei Ken*) is the main technique of the Pegasus saint. It consists in a very rapid discharge of punches in mid-short distance.

He punches really fast, the speed in which he punches even increases later on specially after the fight with Leo Aiolia where is is able to unleash as many punches as Aiolia's lightning bolts.

I wouldn't take Netflix Saint Seiya as a reference to judge wether they are punches or projectiles since that series is not really loyal to the manga.

Comment: Netflix has Saint Seiya? Also the new Saint Seiya movie (the 3D) ones show that some of the saints punches can be long range